# How get contacts info into sms broadcast receiver class?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-contacts

I have an app that works with contacts info when the cell phone receive a SMS, I need to get the contacts info into the SMS receiver class that I create but the problem is when the SMS receiver fetch contacts gave my null pointer exception error because it don't fetch the contacts info, my idea is get all contacts info to compare the number of the SMS sender to get his ID to do other actions in my app.

here's my code:

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
    private static Activity mActivity;
    DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Contact> mContactsArrayList;
    public String str4;
    private ContactManager aContactManager;
    private ArrayList<Contact> ctnList;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Log.d("SMSBroadcastReceiver", "Yes it calls the onReceive");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        String str2 = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
               str2=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                   str4 = str2;     
            }


            if(str.charAt(0)=='#'&&str.length()<=4){

                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager notManager = 
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

                //Configuramos la notificaci�n
                int icono = R.drawable.resultadosmnu;
                CharSequence textoEstado = "Ask-It notification";
                long hora = System.currentTimeMillis();

                Notification notif = 
                    new Notification(icono, textoEstado, hora);
                CharSequence titulo = "New set of response on Askit";
                CharSequence descripcion = "There's available a new set of response on your Survey_Name graph";

                Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, 
                        ProyectoAskitActivity.class);

                PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context, 0, notIntent, 0);

                notif.setLatestEventInfo(
                        context, titulo, descripcion, contIntent);
                notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notManager.notify(icono, notif);
                Contact cnt = queryDetailsForContactNumber(str2);
                Toast toast1 =
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                cnt.getPhoneNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast1.show();
         }
        }

        }                         

    public Contact queryDetailsForContactNumber(String aContactId) {
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Phone._ID,                          // the contact id column
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,                 // the name of the contact
                Phone.NUMBER        // the id of the column in the data table for the image
        };

        final Cursor contact = mActivity.managedQuery(
                Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                Phone.NUMBER+"="+aContactId,                        // filter entries on the basis of the contact id
                null,   // the parameter to which the contact id column is compared to
                null);

        if(contact.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactId =  contact.getInt(
                        contact.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID));
            final String name = contact.getString(
                    contact.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            final String number = contact.getString(
                    contact.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            final Contact aContact = new Contact(contactId, name,null,false,number);


            return aContact;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem, I create a object class called contacts with all the contacts parametres and create an arrayList of contacts and populate it with contacts to get the info to compare one by one to get the info which I need.

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
    DBHelper mDBHelper;
    static Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Contact> ctnList;

     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Log.d("SMSBroadcastReceiver", "Yes it calls the onReceive");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        String str2 = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
               str2=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

            }


            if(str.charAt(0)=='#'&&str.length()<=4){

                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

                ctnList=queryAllContactsWithPhone(context);
                Contact ctn = new Contact();
                int x = ctnList.size();
                int y = 0;
                while(x-1>=y){
                    ctn = ctnList.get(y);
                    if(ctn.getPhoneNumber().compareTo(str2)==0){
                        Toast toast1 =
                                Toast.makeText(context,
                                        ctn.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                        toast1.show();
                    }else{
                        Toast toast1 =
                                Toast.makeText(context,
                                        str2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                        toast1.show();
                    }
                    y++;
                }

         }
        }

        }                         

    public ArrayList<Contact> queryAllContactsWithPhone(Context ct) {

        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Phone.CONTACT_ID,                           // the contact id column
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,                 // the contact display name
                Phone.NUMBER
        };

        final String selection = Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER; // the contact has to have a phone number.
        final String sort = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC";   // the contact has to have a phone number.

        final Cursor contacts = ct.getContentResolver().query(
                Phone.CONTENT_URI,      // the uri for contact provider
                projection, 
                null,                   // if selection = null, retrieve all entries
                null,                       // not required because selection does not contain parameters
                sort);                      // do not order

        final int contactIdColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.CONTACT_ID);
        final int contactDisplayNameColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final int contactPhoneColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

        final ArrayList<Contact> contactsArrayList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        if(contacts.moveToFirst()) {                    // move the cursor to the first entry
            while(!contacts.isAfterLast()) {            // still a valid entry left?
                final int contactId =  contacts.getInt(contactIdColumnIndex);
                final String contactDisplayName=  contacts.getString(contactDisplayNameColumnIndex);
                final String Phones = contacts.getString(contactPhoneColumnIndex);
                final Contact aContact = new Contact();
                aContact.setPhoneNumber(Phones);
                aContact.setName(contactDisplayName);
                aContact.setId(contactId);
                contactsArrayList.add(aContact);
                contacts.moveToNext();              // move to the next entry
            }
        }

        contacts.close();
        return contactsArrayList;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would init a service instead of do that at the receiver.
See this kind of service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html